# How to display same image in ImageView if I click on the horizontal images in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

I have the list of images in horizontal LinearLayout If I click particular image the same image will appear on the above of  single image view.
How can I get the position of Images in Image View.

CODE

```
JSONArray multipleimage = alertObj.getJSONArray(PRODUCT_IMAGES);

/*JSONObject singleimage = multipleimage.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("original_res"));
String singleimg = productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id") + String.valueOf(singleimage);
firstimages=(ImageView)

findViewById(R.id.singleimage);

YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(singleimg,firstimages,options);*/

horizontalimage=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearimage);

if(multipleimage.length()>0)

{
    for (int j = 0; j < multipleimage.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject pimages = multipleimage.getJSONObject(j);
        JSONObject oneimage = multipleimage.getJSONObject(0);
        ii = new ImageView(singleshooppingcart.this);
        multipleimages = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.singleimage);
        ii.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams image = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        image.width = 150;
        image.height = 150;
        image.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
        String multimgs = pimages.getString("original_res");
        String oneimg = oneimage.getString("original_res");
        String[] img2 = multimgs.split("\\.");
        String imagone = productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id") + '/' + img2[0] + '(' + '2' + '0' + '0' + ')' + '.' + img2[1];
        String singleiamges = productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id") + '/' + oneimg;
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(imagone, ii, options);
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(singleiamges, multipleimages, options);
        ii.setLayoutParams(image);
        horizontalimage.addView(ii);
        ii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many approaches for this-

1. Simplest approach is using `ViewGroup#indexOfChild(View child)` method. This will simply return what you want.
2. Or you can use `View#setTag(Object)` and `View#getTag()`, specially if you want to get some thing more than mere index in `onClick`.
3. You can also use `View#setTag(int, Object)` and `View#getTag(int)`, if you want to set more than one tag per view.

Hope below example code for first approach helps-

```
ii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
    // the parameter view here is your imageview, which is clicked.
    // horizontalimage is your LinearLayout, which is a ViewGroup
    int indexOfImage = horizontalimage.indexOfChild(view);
    // do what you want to do with index
    }
});
```

Comment: @Nivethitha added some example code. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote code like this as mentioned below                                                  int indexOfImage = horizontalimage.indexOfChild(view);                 String img1=String.valueOf(indexOfImage);
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(img1, multipleimages, options); but i got error

Comment: You must have got the indexOfImage correctly. After that you need to get the URL of image for that index, but you have just used <code>String.valueOf(int)</code> which will just convert 1 to "1", for example.

Comment: I got indexofImage correctly, but how to display same images in another imageview by using this positon

Comment: i don't how to get the URL of image for that index could u please send me code for that

Comment: Thank you, I got an answer for that index position of an image url

Answer (score 0):

Not tested..try like this...

```
JSONArray multipleimage = alertObj.getJSONArray(PRODUCT_IMAGES);

/*JSONObject singleimage = multipleimage.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("original_res"));
String singleimg = productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id") + String.valueOf(singleimage);
firstimages = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.singleimage);

YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(singleimg,firstimages,options);*/
horizontalimage = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearimage);

if(multipleimage.length()>0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < multipleimage.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject pimages = multipleimage.getJSONObject(j);
        JSONObject oneimage = multipleimage.getJSONObject(0);
        ii = new ImageView(singleshooppingcart.this);
        multipleimages = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.singleimage);            
        ii.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams image = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        image.width = 150;
        image.height = 150;
        image.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
        String multimgs = pimages.getString("original_res");
        String oneimg = oneimage.getString("original_res");
        String[] img2 = multimgs.split("\\.");
        String imagone = productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id") + '/' + img2[0] + '(' + '2' + '0' + '0' + ')' + '.' + img2[1];
        String singleiamges = productpath + alertObj.getString("seller_id") + '/' + oneimg;
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(imagone, ii, options);
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(singleiamges, multipleimages, options);
        ii.setLayoutParams(image);
        horizontalimage.addView(ii);
        ii.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              multipleimages.setImageURI (singleiamges);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it integer or string positionofserverimage

Comment: how can i set the imageview ( multipleimages=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.singleimage);)

Comment: @Nivethitha..what you want to say..not understanding!

Comment: @Nivethitha..you have to do like positionOfServerImage = (int) ( multipleimages.getTag());

Comment: @gupta what i meant if i click image from imageview that same image will appear on another imageview

Comment: @Nivethitha..from this code you are getting the position of image..then just pass this position to another imageview in onclicklistener of first imageview

Comment: i didn't get position of this imageview.i got error                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Nivethitha..I have updated my last answer....not sure that it will work for you or not..

Comment: then skip the position concept and try the method setimageuri @Nivethitha